# How to search for and return multiple elements using a interpolation search c#

Tags: c#, interpolation

I currently have a working interpolation search which can detect a chosen number if it is stored within the array.

My question is; if the number being searched for is stored multiple times in the array how do I search for it multiple times and stop it from detecting the number multiple times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to return multiple elements, you need to return an array of int (or list, or anything that can hold multiple values).

When you find a value, don't return immediately. Search for neighboring elements in the array to see if there is more than one occurrence. You can track index of first occurrence, and last occurrence. Once you checked both left and right side for multiple occurrences, store these values in the array and return the array.